# t-sql 2012 complex select by endyear and most current record

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following table that contains can contain 0,1, or many records
for each endyear when a query is excuted by personID. The enrollmentID key
is not used by any queries in my company. That column only exists since 
 database tables requie an identity key.
       What I need to do is to allow is for a parameter called @endYear to be 
      used and matched against the endYear column in the Enrollment table. 
      The user will be able to select @endYear = 2018 or @endYear = 2017.

I need to select the most current enrollment record based upon end Date 
  and endStatus = 202 or 205.

The problem is when @endYear=2017. I can not select records by personID if 
 records exist where endyear =2018 and (there is not an endStatus = 202
  OR 205).

Here is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Enrollment](
[enrollmentID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
[personID] [int] NOT NULL,
[calendarID] [int] NOT NULL,    
[grade] [varchar](4) NULL,  
[active] [bit] NOT NULL,    
[startDate] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
[startStatus] [varchar](4) NULL,
[startComments] [varchar](250) NULL,
[endDate] [smalldatetime] NULL,
[endStatus] [varchar](4) NULL,
[endYear] [smallint] NOT NULL
)
```

Thus can you show me the t-sql 2012 on how to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you're asking - but to get the latest row (with the highest endDate) for a @personID and @endYear, this is the query to use:

```
SELECT 
  TOP 1 * 
FROM 
  [dbo].[Enrollment] 
WHERE 
  endYear=@endYear AND personID=@PersonID AND endStatus IN (202, 205) 
ORDER BY 
  endDate DESC
```